# ExtJS DateField format Confuse

Tags: javascript, extjs, date-format

I use Ext.form.DateField with specified format is 'd/m/Y', like this:

```
           {
            xtype : 'datefield',
            fieldLabel : 'Value Date <span style="color:red">*</span>',
            name : 'valueDate',
            allowBlank : false,
            blankText : 'Please enter a Start Date',
            msgTarget : 'under',
            format : 'd/m/Y',
            emptyText : 'dd/mm/yyyy'}
```

I want this component to complete the input value automatically with given format after it press tab key. I mean if I input the text '04022015' , it must display that text as '04/02/2015'.
But when I input the text '04022015' and press tab key it display as 02/04/2015, I don't know how to make it work as I expect above. Could you please help me on this?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [altFormats](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Date-cfg-altFormats) config. By default the parsing patterns are:

```
"m/d/Y|n/j/Y|n/j/y|m/j/y|n/d/y|m/j/Y|n/d/Y|m-d-y|m-d-Y|m/d|m-d|md|mdy|mdY|d|Y-m-d|n-j|n/j"
```

Where | is the separator between different formats. As you can see the order is m-d-y by default. Just change this string to:

```
"dmy|dmY|d/m/y|d/m/Y|d-m-y|d-m-Y" // or similar...
```

Any formats you wish to be able to parse need to be there.